# How can I create a configurable product with its associate products using SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, api, soap-api-v2

i m create a configurable product. product r create but when i going to its detail through admin than it asking a color and size checkbox option.

can anyone tell me how can i pass it.

i m access magento soap v2. http:/testhost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

**my code :**

```
                        string nav_mgntoUsername = "uSernAmE/"; string nav_mgntoAPIkey =  "apiKey000999/*";

                        TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.MagentoService nav_mgntoSRV = new TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.MagentoService();
                        string nav_mgntoLogin = nav_mgntoSRV.login(nav_mgntoUsername, nav_mgntoAPIkey);

                        string nav_productType = "configurable";
                        string nav_attributeSetId = "4"; // This is the ID of the Catalog Product Attribute Set

                        string nav_productSku = "00TestCnfg000";
                        string[] nav_mgntoWebsite = new {"1"};

                        TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.catalogProductCreateEntity nav_mgntoProduct = new TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.catalogProductCreateEntity();

                        TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity nav_mgntoProductSTK = new TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity();
                        nav_mgntoProductSTK.qty = "0";
                        nav_mgntoProductSTK.is_in_stock = 0;

                        TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.associativeEntity[] nav_mgntoProductAttrS = new TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.associativeEntity[4];
                        TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.associativeEntity nav_mgntoProductAttr = new TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.associativeEntity();          // color
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.key = "color";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.value = "15";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttrS[0] = nav_mgntoProductAttr;
      // brand
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.key = "manufacturer";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.value = "9";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttrS[1] = nav_mgntoProductAttr;
      // size
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.key = "size";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.value = "150";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttrS[2] = nav_mgntoProductAttr;
      // page layout
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.key = "page_layout";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttr.value = "one_column";
                        nav_mgntoProductAttrS[3] = nav_mgntoProductAttr;
                        TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity nav_mgntoProductAttE = new TestMagantoProduct.NaviMangentoAPI.catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity();
                        nav_mgntoProductAttE.single_data = nav_mgntoProductAttrS;

                        nav_mgntoProduct.name = "test config product name";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.description = "test configu product description";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.short_description = "test config product short desc";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.websites = nav_mgntoWebsite;
                        nav_mgntoProduct.meta_description = "test config product meta desc";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.meta_keyword = "test config product meta keyword";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.meta_title = "test config product meta title";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.weight = "2.00";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.status = "1";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.url_key = "test config product url key";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.visibility = "1";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.price = "0.99";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.tax_class_id = "0";
                        nav_mgntoProduct.gift_message_available = "1";

                        nav_mgntoProduct.stock_data = nav_mgntoProductSTK;

                        string valPrdCategory = "9";
                        string[] categoriesArr = valPrdCategory.Split(',');
                        nav_mgntoProduct.categories = categoriesArr;

                        nav_mgntoProduct.additional_attributes = nav_mgntoProductAttE;

                        int intStatus;
                        try
                        {
                            intStatus = nav_mgntoSRV.catalogProductCreate(nav_mgntoLogin, nav_productType, nav_attributeSetId, "t_"+nav_productSku, nav_mgntoProduct, "");
                            n_forcount++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex1)
                        {
                            string strError = "";
                            intStatus = 0;
                            strError = ex1.Message.ToString();

                            MessageBox.Show(strError + " " + ex1.Source.ToString());

                        }
```

with regards,
Rashesh

Answer (score 1):

Rashesh, first you need to create a simple product(s) with given color and manufacturer.  Then create a configurable product and associate it with the simple product.

Comment: Hi, first thank you very much to you reply. i m all ready to do that but it not comes in configurable of associate product.